# strcat function in C

Tags: c, string

I have the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[1000]="/";
    char unit[1000]="Hai";
    strcat(str1,unit);
    printf("\nvalue of unit: %s\n", unit);
    return 0;
}
```

`strcat` should append `"/"` to `"Hai"`. So the expected output of `printf` is 'value of unit: Hai/', but I get the output as 'value of unit: Hai'

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just read the docs of `strcat()`: it will tell you that it is called with `strcat(dest, src)`.

So in your case, `str1` will contain `"/Hai"`. If you want `unit` to be `"Hai/"`, you should call `strcat(unit, str1)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
strcat(str1,unit);
//     ^dst  ^src

printf("\nvalue of unit: %s\n", unit);
//                              ^src
```

Use:

```
strcat(unit,str1);
```

Note: most C functions expect the destination first and then the source.